# Controller receiving default values on POST

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, post, controller

I'm trying to make a very simple web service using .NET Core 3.1 in OS X using Visual Studio for Mac.

I started a Web Application template project and after that included a simple controller.

To enable the controller, I added in `Startup.cs` the following lines:

```
     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
             {
                 endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                 endpoints.MapControllers(); //This
             });
```

and

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddControllers(); //and this

        }
```

So my controller looks like this:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {

        [HttpPost("test")]
        public void Read(TestEntityModel tem)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tem.txt);
        }
```

I'm debugging what arrives to Read() method, but `tem` object looks empty all the time.

The `TestEntityModel` class looks like this:

```
    public class TestEntityModel
    {
        public string txt { get; set; }
        public float number { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm calling this method with the following AJAX code:

```
    function send() {
        var TestEntityModel = new Object();
        TestEntityModel.txt = "hola";
        TestEntityModel.number = 7;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/values/test',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: TestEntityModel,
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Error in Operation');
            }
        });


    }
```

But no idea what's going on.

Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: Please try adding `[FromBody]` to this argument like: `public void Read([FromBody]TestEntityModel tem)`

Comment: you should also add `[ApiController]` attribute, it helps in model binding

Comment: And changing ``data`` to ``data: JSON.stringify(TestEntityModel)``

Comment: @DeepakMishra comment was what I was missing. Quite strange, because with GET was working fine. I added `[ApiController]`and it worked also with POST. I don't know why worked with GET. Also, including the JSON.stringify was a step I was missing, @Sajid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherit from APICONTROLLER and adding [FromBody] attribute should do it. If not check with fiddler how your request is sending the data. I would also confirm that you net core app has the default media type formatted as json, I think it does but confirm it.

```
public ActionResult<Pet> Create([FromBody] Pet pet)
```

Also take a look at this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1